# Check if a video have sound with ffprobe (for bash use)

Tags: bash, macos, ffprobe

I'm trying to detect if my videos has sound.

At first I tried to make a 30s sample from it, and check the sizes, but the problem is those are encoded in CBR, which means the sizes are always going to be the same.

But I've discovered ffprobe, which seams quite complicated to manipulate. Can I check if the levels of a video are higher than *any number* ?

edit : Also, those video files might have an audio stream, but without sound. To sum up, I need to check if there is an audio stream, and in that case, if there is real sound and not only silence.

Comment: This should help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/21447100/2836621

Comment: Yes of course I've seen that topic, but it suppose that there is or there isn't an audio stream. I should have been more precise : I want to handle the possibility that there is an audio stream but without noise. Which makes that topic irrelevant.

Comment: Instead of ffprobe you can try to use `ffmpeg` with `silencedetect` filter.