# How to get current frame from a video in android Surfaceview?

Tags: java, android, frame, surfaceview

I want to create an app that is playing a live video . Have to capture the current frame while clicking the button.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can get frame using [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long,%20int%29)

```
private fun getVideoFrame() {
    val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    retriever.setDataSource(VIDEO_PATH)
    val bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(yourTime, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. When I click the button the app will be crashed and the error is the following...
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:76)
        at qc.yotm.mes.com.yo_qc.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:306)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)

Comment: It means your the path is invalid. make sure you have the VIDEO_PATH present correctly

Comment: The video is playing

Comment: I assume your streaming the video from url / uri not from the local path.  So in your case use this  setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri)

Comment: Yes, it is an RTSP link.

Comment: I have tried that too... It shows the following error.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: qc.yotm.mes.com.yo_qc, PID: 2128
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:172)
        at qc.yotm.mes.com.yo_qc.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:307)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)

Comment: It seams your url might be expecting some additional params as well (like headers) etc. So you need to check for that method in setDataSource in MediaMetadataRetriever documentation

Comment: My Code is
   MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(liveVideoPath);
                        retriever.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),uri);
                        Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(60000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
                        imageViewNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imageViewNew.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: check my old answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483591/3983054

Comment: did your liveVideoPath url is playing directly in your media player ? else your adding any extra parameters to play it ?

Comment: mediaPlayer.setDataSource(liveVideoPath);

Comment: still the same issue ? I have updated my answer with few more points

Comment: Yes, still the problem occurs.